# sampling: question about variance estimation

Tags: variance, estimation, sampling, mean, monte-carlo

I'm new in this field, I'm studying montecarlo methods for sampling; I understand that,with a basic approach, we have an estimation for the mean
$$\hat{\mu}=\frac{1}{n}\sum f(x)$$
and for variance
$$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$
so I read that, while $n\to +\infty,\hat{\sigma}^2\to 0$ and this I don't understand...
For example, we can imagine that I have a population that follows a Normal distribution as
$$N(10,3)$$
Now, I want to use MC to estimate this distribution; more sample I take from this distribution, more little becomes my estimated variance, going to $0$...but my variance estimation should go to $3$ to be a good estiamation of the real $\sigma^2$...
where is my error or my misunderstanding?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ is the *variance of the mean* of $n$ i.i.d. samples from a distribution with variance $\sigma^2$ (and similarly $n \sigma^2$ is the *variance of the sum*).  As $n$ increases, you increasingly expect the sample mean to be close to the population mean

Comment: so, $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ is not $Var(f(x))$ but $Var(\hat{\mu})$? this is my error, right?

Comment: @volpeross this is closely related to standard error of the mean. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error (but variance instead of standard deviation)

Comment: @volperossa.  I would prefer to say that for a sample you have  $\text{Var}\left(\frac1n \sum_i X_i \right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$, as I am not totally clear what you mean by $f(x)$